# Post to user page from app on server

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have got the APP token using    https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token

I have got the usser access token using     https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id

I now what to to publish on the user FaceBook page  and it appears I need to USER_ID

Where is that?

I am looking to publish using https://graph.facebook.com/[USER ID]/feed

Answer (score 0):

The user id is the number or facebook user of the user where you want to post...
When you see the url from your home you see:

```
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=4

https://www.facebook.com/zuck
```

In this case you can use 4 or zuck for that.